# how can i make my database er diagram to code?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've made this ER diagram for my college project but i have to use forward engineering to see SQL code. MySQL version is 8.0.27

when i try it, it come up with error like below.

> Executing SQL script in server
> ERROR: Error 3734: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'editor_ismi' for constraint 'fk_editor_ismi' in the referenced table 'editor'

SQL Code:

```sql
-- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `mydb`.`kitap`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`kitap` (
      `isbn` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `editor_ismi` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `yazar_ismi` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `yazar_adres` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `kitap_yili` INT NOT NULL,
      `kitap_baslik` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `kitap_fiyat` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`isbn`),
      INDEX `fk_editor_ismi_idx` (`editor_ismi` ASC) VISIBLE,
      INDEX `fk_yazar_ismi_idx` (`yazar_ismi` ASC) VISIBLE,
      INDEX `fk_yazar_adres_idx` (`yazar_adres` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_editor_ismi`
        FOREIGN KEY (`editor_ismi`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`editor` (`editor_ismi`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_yazar_ismi`
        FOREIGN KEY (`yazar_ismi`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Yazar` (`yazar_ismi`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_yazar_adres`
        FOREIGN KEY (`yazar_adres`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Yazar` (`yazar_ismi`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed
> Fetching back view definitions in final form.
> Nothing to fetch

[screenshot of my er diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWOCR.png)

Comment: does  version of mysql support visible indexes?. Select version() and add result to question.

Comment: i added it's 8.0.27

Comment: btw sorry for that complicated error text. i'm new here so i need to learn how to use panels.

Comment: No idea if or how workbench manages this but referenced tables have to be created before referencing tables. ALSO mydb is for mysql's purposes you should not be creating stuff in mydb..